# INSERT INTO based on result of WHERE in double JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, the schema is not mine. It is horrible and very confusing. And a warning - this is complex.

I have 3 tables - `tbl_a`, `tbl_b`, and `tbl_c`. `switch` is actually a property of entities (records) in `tbl_a`. But it is only accessible via a `JOIN` on `tbl_b` and then `tbl_c`:

```
  +---------+         +---------+         +---------+
  |  tbl_a  |         |  tbl_b  |         |  tbl_c  |
  +---------+         +---------+         +---------+
  | a_id    |    +--> | b_id    |    +--> | c_id    |
  | b_fk    | <--+    | c_fk    | <--+    | switch  |
  +---------+         +---------+         +---------+

  +---------+
  | tbl_his |
  +---------+
  | his_id  |
  | a_fk    |
  | coef    |
  +---------+
```

To add a feature I need to create a fourth table (`tbl_his`) - which I have done. In this table I have a `coef` column which could take any number from 1 to 100. I need to populate table `tbl_his` one record per `tbl_a`'s record. With the present data `switch` is either `0`, or `1`.

For each record in `tbl_a` with a related `switch` of `0` I should add a record to `tbl_his` as
 `NULL, 'a_id', '100'`

If for a record the switch is `1` I should add the following record to `tbl_his`:
 `NULL, 'a_id', '50'`

Would this query do half of the job? Any way to do both `50` records and `100` records in one go?

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_his` (`his_id`, `a_fk`, `coef`) VALUES (NULL, 'tbl_a.id', '100') 
WHERE (
SELECT tbl_a.id 
FROM tbl_a
LEFT JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.b_fk = tbl_b.id
LEFT JOIN tbl_c ON tbl_b.c_fk = tbl_c.c_id
WHERE tbl_c.switch = '0')
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. There should be no `WHERE` after the `VALUES()` list.  Also missing a backquote in `FROM \`tbl_a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as an `INSERT INTO...WHERE` query syntax. What you want is [`INSERT INTO...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html).

i.e.

```
INSERT INTO 
  tbl_his (a_fk, coef) 
SELECT 
  tbl_a.id, 
  CASE WHEN tbl_c.switch = 0 THEN 100 ELSE 50 END
FROM
  tbl_a
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_b
ON
  tbl_a.b_fk = tbl_b.id
LEFT JOIN
  tbl_c
ON
  tbl_b.c_fk = tbl_c.c_id
```

[MySQL Manual :: Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Comment: Thanks. So here `SELECT` does the job of `VALUES` too?

Comment: Yes. The result of the SELECT query is what gets inserted. As many rows as are returned will be inserted. I linked to the manual page explaining everything.

Comment: +1 but you missed an opportunity to write CASE Switch WHEN... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the LEFT on joins. Your where clause is in an illegal place. Insert values from a query and calculate coef. If all switch values are 0 or 1 you can drop the last line.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_his (his_id, a_fk, coef)
  SELECT NULL, tbl_a.id, 100-50*tbl_c.switch
  FROM tbl_a 
  JOIN tbl_b ON tbl_a.b_fk = tbl_b.id
  JOIN tbl_c ON tbl_b.c_fk = tbl_c.c_id
  WHERE switch BETWEEN 0 AND 1;
```